# Split an array with custom function

Tags: javascript, arrays, algorithm, ecmascript-6, split

i would like to split an array into multiple chunks but applying a function to it to decide how to create the chunks.

For example, if i have an array of letters, numbers or letters and numbers, apply a function to the array to split it into array of arrays of the previous categories.

```
let arr = ['a', 'b', '1', '2', 'a1', 'a2', 'c', '3', 'a3']
myChunkFunction(arr, myCustomSplitFunction)

// result
[['a','b','c'], ['1','2','3'], ['a1', 'a2','a3']]
```

Lodash has a chunk function but it splits into n chunks, also array has a slice function but you need to specify the begin and the end so how could i split with a custom function.

Comment: What is the question? What you have there seems fine, you just need to define `myCustomSplitFunction`.

Comment: I don't have a chunk function that applies custom functions.

Comment: It would just be `function myChunkFunction(array, splitFunction) { return splitFunction(array); }`, and then you could call it exactly as you have in your code above.

Comment: If you need to do manipulations like this commonly, maybe consider using a library like [lodash](https://lodash.com). In particular, you could do this easily via their `_.groupBy` and `_.values` functions.

Comment: The question is fine. Stop downvote just because you don't see: "my question is...." .

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try doing this

```
let arr = ['a', 'b', '1', '2', 'a1', 'a2', 'c', '3', 'a3']

const splitFn = (str) => Number.isInteger(+str) ? 0 : str.length == 1 ? 1 : 2
const myChunkFunction = (arr, fn) => arr.reduce((r,c) => {
   let t = fn(c)
   r[t] = [...r[t], c]
   return r
}, [[],[],[]])

console.log(myChunkFunction(arr, splitFn))
```

Answer (score 1):

Here is a way to do this via ES6:

```js
let arr = ['a', 'b', '1', '2', 'a1', 'a2', 'c', '3', 'a3']

const splitFn = (str) => Number.isInteger(+str) ? 0 : str.length == 1 ? 1 : 2
const myChunkFunction = (arr, fn) => arr.reduce((r,c) => {
   let t = fn(c)
   r[t] = [...r[t], c]
   return r
}, [[],[],[]])

console.log(myChunkFunction(arr, splitFn))
```

The `typeFn` plays the role of filtering the elements to `number`, `string with 1 length` and `other`. That output is used by the `myChunkFunction` to place the element in the right array.

You could do something like this with less control and in one line with  [`reduce`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/Reduce) and ES6 array spread:

```js
let arr = ['a', 'b', '1', '2', 'a1', 'a2', 'c', '3', 'a3']

const result = arr.reduce((r,c) => 
  (Number.isInteger(+c) ? r[0] = [...r[0], c] : 
  c.length == 1 ? r[1] = [...r[1], c] : r[2] = [...r[2], c], r), [[],[],[]])

console.log(result)
```

You start with `[[],[],[]]` and fill each of the sub arrays based on number, length of the string == 1, other lenghts.

You could wrap that in a function.

Comment: He wants to extract a key from each element __by a given function__ and use that for re-grouping the elements. In your solution, you __implicitly__ used the identity function to extract the key.

Comment: "I would like to split an array into multiple chunks ___but applying a function to it to decide how to create the chunks___". And: `myChunkFunction(arr, myCustomSplitFunction)`. The second param is the custom function.

Answer (score 1):

### Hint

The key to the answer is to, somehow, reorganize the source array such that all the elements with the same key will be in the same place.

The easiest way I can think to solve it is by using `hash-map`. Each element in the `hash-map` will be a different array containing all the elements with the same key.

Try it for your self before you keep reading and see the full solution.

---

### The implementation

As you can see, I solved it as functional as possible. To avoid mutations, I used `reduce` to iterate over the source array and put each element in the hashmap (by generating a key from the element).

I recreate the final hash-map over and over using *shallow copy*. Finally, I convert the hash-map to an array of array (because that was your demand) using `Object.values`

```js
const splitArrayByKey = extractKey => array => {
    const arraysByKey_obj = array.reduce((hashMapOfArrays,element)=> {
        const key = extractKey(element);
        
        // if we already added an element with the same key, 
        // then we add the current element to there.
        // else, we create a new key and put the current element there.
        if(hashMapOfArrays.hasOwnProperty(key))
            return {
                ...hashMapOfArrays,
                [key]: [...hashMapOfArrays[key],element]
            };
        return {
            ...hashMapOfArrays,
            [key]: [element]
        };
    },{});

    // transform the arraysByKey_obj to an array of arrays:
    return Object.values(arraysByKey_obj);
};

// example 1:
const result1 = splitArrayByKey(element=>element)([1,2,3,1,2,3]);
console.log(result1);

console.log('------------------');

// example 2:
const result2 = splitArrayByKey(element=>element.id)([{id:1,x:1},{id:{},x:2},{id:"id",x:3},{id:1,x:4}]);
console.log(result2);
```

Answer (score 0):

```
const arr = ['a', 'b', '1', '2', 'a1', 'a2', 'c', '3', 'a3'];
const getClassification = function(x){
    const hasNumber = x.split('').some(x => parseFloat(x));
    const hasChar = x.split('').some(x => !parseFloat(x));

    if(!parseFloat(x) && (!hasNumber && hasChar)) return 0;
    else if(parseFloat(x)) return 1;
    else return 2;
}

const myChunkFunction = function(arr, classifier){
    let jaggedArray = [[], [], []];

    arr.forEach(x => {
        jaggedArray[classifier(x)].push(x);
    })

    return jaggedArray;
}

console.log(myChunkFunction(arr, getClassification));
```

I think this satisfies.